# Where is this place?

Tags: egypt, locate-this

Can anyone tell me the exact location of this historical site?

[image]

Is it in Egypt or Iraq?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears to be the [Temple of Karnak](https://www.planetware.com/tourist-attractions-/karnak-temple-complex-of-karnak-egy-qena-karn.htm) complex in Luxor, Egypt, more specifically, the "Avenue of Sphinxes".  If you compare the photo you posted with the one in the link, you can match the sphinxes missing their heads. You can also match the small bushes on the left of the path.

[image]

<sup>(Note: Image taken from the link)</sup>